# Can an XML catalog refer to files in a separate JAR?

Tags: java, jax-ws, xmlcatalog

I have several JAX-WS clients, each talking to a different SOAP service, that I generate with **wsimport** and package into its own JAR. Each client has its own XML catalog so that **wsimport** can work locally with WSDL's and XSD's stored alongside the project.

The actual applications which use these client each have their own [XML Catalog](http://metro.java.net/nonav/2.2/guide/ch02.html#xml-catalog) to save on network calls for the WSDL at runtime. These are basically unions of the XML catalogs of the clients the application is using.

This all works but the catch is that, in addition to the *application* XML catalog, I still have to keep a copy of the WSDL's with the application JAR since the URI's are relative to the XML catalog. So I need to remember to update the *application*'s copy of the WSDL whenever the *client*'s copy is updated.

Is there a way to say, in my **jax-ws-catalog.xml**, that the WSDL is in another JAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no way but to package the WSDL's and XSD's alongside my **jax-ws-catalog.xml** file.